# Display List within ListView Inside Datatemplate Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display the contents of a list within a class inside a datatemplate.
As it stands I have a Xaml page that is bound to a view model that displays data in a list view.
The binding and data display is working fine so I will leave out the code that fetches the data.

My Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Watson.Views.MainRoutePageViewDetail">

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RouteStopsDetails}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid Padding="5">

                        <!--Main Grid-->
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Label Text="{Binding RouteName}"  TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                    </Grid>                   

                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>


</ListView>
```

The class that it is bound to (that is RouteStopsDetails):

```
public class RouteInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RouteName { get; set; }
    public string Stops { get; set; }
    public string DayOf { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<RouteStops> RouteStops { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

}
```

And the RouteStops Class (used with the list in the previous class):

```
public class RouteStops
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RouteName { get; set; }
    public string StopOnRoute { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNum { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string TotalWeight { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can display all the data within the RouteInfo except the RouteStops list within the RouteInfo class. For instance you can see the label in the Xaml that is bound to RouteName, that is showing fine.

As stated I know the binding works because things like RouteName show in the list just fine. But I dont know how to display the RouteStops list.

Things I have tried:

Cant display a listview within a listview on Android.

Tried to put a nested content page and a content view within the same page and then subsequently put a list view within that. That did not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to reflect it, but nested ListViews are not supported and you shouldn't attempt to use them in such a fashion.

Comment: I did try nested listview it was a spectacular fail. I was wondering if there was some smart way it can be done. Previously I just built the whole page in the code behind but as per the request from my manager it must be done in Xaml.

Comment: Have you investigated using a grouped listview? Example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping)

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks.